# PHP preg_match_all: regular expression assistence

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a question about expression. I've looked the forum through but I'm still stuck with the same problem. I found a sample on the php.net page which has an expression similar to what I'm looking for but still no success.
What I'm trying to achieve is, to get words which are between {}. IE:

`$html = '<h1>Hello {NAME_P}, today is {TODAY}.</h1>';`

The expression I'm using is `preg_match_all("/{[^}]*}/", $html, $hooks);` but it returns `0 = Array`.

I would like to have the strings NAME_P and TODAY as result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try capturing the group using brackets around the wanted parts: `preg_match_all("/{([^}]*)}/", $html, $hooks);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture them I believe. To do that, use brackets as follows:

```
preg_match_all("/{([^}]*)}/", $html, $hooks);
                  ^     ^
```